# Volume of tetrahedron by decomposition

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Let $T$ be a tetrahedron with sidelength $s$. It's volume is proportional to $s^3$.
$$V(T)=ks^3$$
Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be tetrahedra with sidelength $s_1=\frac 13 s$ and $s_2=\frac 23 s$

Can't we decompose $V(T)$ as follows?

$$V(T)=ks^3=4V(T_2)-6V(T_1)=4k(\frac 23s)^3-6k(\frac 13s)^3$$

The idea behind that is to count 4 $T_2$ inside of $T$ and subtract the overlaps $T_1$ that happen at the edges of $T$.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBUUJ.png) shows an example of $T$ with sidelength $s=\sqrt{2}$

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRrgy.png) shows $T_{2A}=T_2$ which shares the corner $A$ with $T$.

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZjvI.png) shows $T_{2B}=T_2$ which shares the corner $B$ with $T$.

Each of the 4 large $T_2$ shares 1 corner with $T$.

Every 2 instances of $T_2$ overlap in a small region $T_1$ like so

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIzPn.png) shows $T_{1AB}$ which shares the edge $AB$ with $T$.

I must be missing something however since the equation above yields $\frac{26}{27}ks^3$

What am I missing?

Edit: Found it! :) Visualizing  a bit better in geogebra, as @ChrisLewis suggested, showed it is the [topological dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_polyhedron#Topological_duality) of $T$ hidden in the center which is also a tetrahedron $T_1$. It's volume is of course exactly what was missing before.

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8via.png) shows that 3 $T_2$ form a valley which the 4th one with it's flat bottom surface can't fill completly.
By the way this region is of course also where the pivotmechanism in the Pyraminx is hidden.

So we got:
$$V(T)=ks^3=4V(T_2)-6V(T_1)+V(T_1)=4k(\frac 23s)^3-6k(\frac 13s)^3+k(\frac 13s)^3=ks^3$$

Comment: Can you illustrate  how to have 4 T2  too large and  corrected by 6 T1? It just does not work.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow without a diagram but I wonder if you're missing another intersection, with volume $\frac{1}{27}ks^3$. This looks a bit like an inclusion-exclusion. Of course, if there is a missing piece, all you're left with is $ks^3=ks^3$ - not much help for finding a volume formula.

Comment: @ChrisLewis Yeah my original idea was to calculate the volume this way but at this point I'm just wondering which small piece I'm not counting in to get $ks^3 = ks^3$

Comment: I'm afraid even with the diagrams it's a bit hard to see, but my guess would be there's an intersection right in the middle. I think (not sure) you can get geogebra to show you all the intersections between the objects; you could set all of them up then selectively show/hide to see the region you're interested in.

Comment: This may help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyraminx

Comment: @BobDobbs Haha where do you think I got the idea? ;)

Comment: The central tetrahedron with side $1/3$ is external to all your $2/3$ tetrahedra, hence you must add it to get the whole volume.

Answer (score 0):

I think it goes like
$$4×8-6×1+4×0-1×0+1=27.$$

I imagined [Pyraminx](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyraminx). I think, the piece in the middle does not belong to any T2. Right?

By the way, I am bad at solving Rubik's cube.

Comment: Yup exactly! What do the termes  $4\times0$ and $1\times0$ mean in your equation though? Is this from some kindof generalized formula?